# how to convert textbox value to datetime

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime, datepicker

I am using a date picker and display the date being chosen in a textbox. The format display as 14-05-2015 10:42

I am trying to pass this value into a method  as below.

```
public String GetTimestamp(DateTime value)
        {
            return value.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
           //return value.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss");

        }
```

I declare value string taskDate = txtDate.Text
how can I convert it into DATETIME format and pass into this method?

I tried several method like parseexact or convert and it is not working.. it will give me an string error.

script for date picker

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#<%=txtDate.ClientID %>").dynDateTime({
                showsTime: true,
                ifFormat: "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",
                daFormat: "%l;%M %p, %e %m, %Y",
                align: "BR",
                electric: false,
                singleClick: false,
                displayArea: ".siblings('.dtcDisplayArea')",
                button: ".next()"
            });
        });
</script>
```

Comment: what is your regional setting date format?

Comment: Have you test it on other machine?

Comment: my regional format is like this TO_DATE('2015-05-28 11:19:38'), and what do u mean by test on other machine?

Comment: I suspect your PC's regional setting format, So I want you to try your application on other machine.

Comment: so how can I change my regional setting to fit with the format i need?

Comment: pls check my answer and let me know what is your current format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [TryParseExact](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
 var dt = DateTime.Now;
 var enUS = new CultureInfo("en-US");
 if(DateTime.TryParseExact(taskDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", enUS, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
 {

 }
```

Or

```
 if(DateTime.TryParseExact(taskDate, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", null, DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
 {

 }
```

**Updating**

Test: https://dotnetfiddle.net/D0UdiV

Comment: Peyman thanks for the comment, but its not working.. it will skip the if statement.

Comment: @Handsome, can you post the sample value of taskDate? Coz I've tested with value like '2015-05-28 12:00:00' and was working fine

Comment: 2015-05-13 11:28:23 is one of the value i get from the date picker

Comment: may I know what do u put in the if statement?

Comment: @Handsome, have you seen the link that I added?

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateTime.TryParse](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ch92fbc1%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) with the appropriate culture for your datepicker string format.

Something like:

```
String timeStamp = null;
DateTime dateValue;
if (DateTime.TryParse(taskDate, CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("fr-FR"), DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
{
    timeStamp = GetTimestamp(dateValue);
}

...
```

Example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/C44uNo

Or make sure the culture is appropriately set for your application globally.

Comment: it will skip the if statement. I do tried this method. what I need is parse it instead of try only. therefore, if I put in if statement. its will skip the parse coz parsing fails. any other method can do it?

Comment: If it fails then it is not possible to turn your string into a `DateTime`. It cannot understand the string from your datepicker. Can you post an example of what the datepicker string looks like? Have you tried debugging `txtDate.Text` to see what is *actually* in there?

Comment: i posted above, the txtDate value is 14-05-2015 10:42:67

Comment: kspearrin I posted the javascript for date time picker.

Comment: Updated answer. Use the appropriate `CultureInfo` for your date string format. See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5hh873ya%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

Comment: Change `txtDate` to `taskDate` or `txtDate.Text`

Comment: still the same, if statement bring skipped. :(

Answer (score 0):

You should check your datetime format at control panel -> regional setting.
[image]